# How can I create two UI elements from one store in extjs?

Tags: extjs

How can I add two different sets of data from the same store to be reflected in any two UI elements at the same time?

This is my store:

---

```
Ext.define('CPC.store.Website.StatisticChartByDate', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    fields: [
        'click',
        'click2',
        'ctr',
        'true_ctr',
        'ctr2',
        'true_ctr2',
        'click_fraud',
        'click_fraud2',
        ...
    ],
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: '/***/***/get-statistic-chart',
    extraParams: {typeCP: Ext.util.Cookies.get('typeCP')},
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'data.chart',
        statistic: 'data.statistic'
    }
},
listeners:{
    load:function (store, records) {

    }
}
});
```

---

This is my json data:

---

```
{
    "data":{
        'statistic': {...}
        'chart' : {...}
    }
}
```

---

Image:https://www.dropbox.com/s/3zyxkzu5ky77710/statistic.png

please, help me..!

Many thanks..!

Comment: i'm not sure what you are after, please elaborate.

Comment: @NDM: i want to render 'chart' data for chart and 'statistic' data for FieldContainer below. Image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3zyxkzu5ky77710/statistic.png.

Answer (score 0):

In my application, I have one store and I needed to swap out the proxy calls. I found this solution on StackOverflow, thanks to Saki:

```
flGridStore.getProxy().url =  '../include/db_searchfilesbydate.php'; //<--Saki magic :)
```